# date / time condition

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have this code, and i want to execute the sql query only if the requested operation is made on specific date. ( for example if i set the date 4.05.2015, the query will be made only on that day, if i try to make the query on 5.05.2015, nothing will happen .
Thx in advice

```
$con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);

$sql2 = "UPDATE `nume` SET `venit3` = '".$_GET['box3']."' WHERE `nr` = '".$_GET['nr']."';";
mysql_query($sql2);
```

Comment: just compare the date with now or current date if matched then run query else nothing

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = "2015-05-05";
$today = date('Y-m-d');

if ($date == $today){

$con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);

$sql2 = "UPDATE `nume` SET `venit3` = '".$_GET['box3']."' WHERE `nr` = '".$_GET['nr']."';";
mysql_query($sql2);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to wrap your code in a statement that actually checks whether if the submission date is valid:

```
$check_date = (some date as a string);
$check_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($check_date));
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');

if ($check_date == $current_date) {
$con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);

$sql2 = "UPDATE `nume` SET `venit3` = '".$_GET['box3']."' WHERE `nr` = '".$_GET['nr']."';";
mysql_query($sql2);
}
```

Bear in mind that this example assumes that $check_date is initially a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO. Then check the date as numbers and LPB1l suggests.

```
$box = $_GET['box3'];
$number = $_GET['nr'];

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");  
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "
    UPDATE `nume`   
    SET `venit3` = :box,    
    WHERE `nr` = :number
    "; 

    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $statement->bindValue(":box", $box);
    $statement->bindValue(":number", $number);   

    $count = $statement->execute();    

}
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```